# VuePress extended markdown-it TOC

Tags: javascript, vuepress

I'm using [[toc]] in my README.md file and it displays level 2, 3 (##, ###) headlines in the Table of Contents automatically. If I try to change this in my  config file according to the documentation

```
toc: { includeLevel: [1, 2] },
```

it doesn't show any change? Is there an error in VuePress?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameters like this:

```
md.use(require("markdown-it-table-of-contents"), {
    includeLevel: [1, 2]
});
```